# How do I find this trace?

Tags: matrices, summation

Let matrices be $X=\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\5&1\end{bmatrix}$ , $Y=\begin{bmatrix}4&5\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$ and $Z=\begin{bmatrix}4&-5\\-3&4\end{bmatrix}$, then what is the value of $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{tr(X(YZ)^k)}{2^k}$$

**What do I already know**: $tr(A)$ symbolises the Trace of matrix $A$ that is, the sum of it's primary diagonal element. But, how am I suposed to find the trace of such a summation? Please help.

(I'm new to eigenvalue concepts so kindly explain them, if required in solution of this question)

Comment: $YZ=I$  (the unit matrix), so it shouldn't be too hard…

Comment: So basically I did a blunder in multiplication. Thank you for pointing that out @Bernard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $YZ$ is the identity matrix, so is $(YZ)^k$. So the top size of the fraction is basically $tr(X)$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\text{tr}(X)}{2^k} = 3\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = 6$$
The last step is [a well known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), but can be done explicitly by using the sum of a geometric series.